# Parameter and Function with the same name

Tags: python

On a Python assignment, I had to make the following two functions:

```
move(board, move)
undomove(board, move)
```

Having an argument with the same name as the function seems like a bad practice to me. I already contacted the professor to change it, but out of curiosity, is it possible to call the `move` function from inside the `undomove`, or to use recursion on the `move`? Inside these functions, `move` refers to the argument.

(Python 3, if it matters)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a handle on `move` (the function), however it will require some additional gymnastics.

```
def move(move):
    print(move,"inside move")

def undomove(move):
    print (move,"inside undomove")
    this_mod =__import__(__name__)
    this_mod.move(move)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    move(1)
    undomove(2)
```

Generally though, I would definitely avoid naming a local variable with the same name as a function that I will need in that function.

As far as style is concerned, creating a function `def move(move): ...` is definitely a little weird, and it would make the casual reader think that you're trying to write a recursive function, so I would definitely avoid that.  Writing `undomove(move)` when `move` is already defined in the module scope as a function is a little less weird, but it still might cause confusion at a quick glance (is it a local variable?  is it the function?) so I would probably avoid that one as well.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of options here, but ruling out the simplest (renaming `move`), there are a few others.

Firstly, you could create another name for the function, so you can use that when `move` gets overridden:

```
def move(...):
   ...

move_ = move

def undomove(..., move):
   move_(...)
```

This works as functions in Python are objects like any other - so you can just assign them to variables.

Another option would be to place the functions in a class, so they are in a namespace - meaning you access the method as `self.move()` and the parameter as `move`. That said, if you assignment requires that the functions be top-level, that isn't an option.

Comment: Also, putting functions inside a class just to have a clean namespace seems a little fishy (everything would have to be declared as `@staticmethod` or similar).

Comment: @mgilson True, although it might be that the problem could be better encapsulated by a move class, with a ``perform()`` and ``undo()`` method, but that's some wild speculation (and may be a massive over-complication).

Comment: Yeah, in that case I agree (+1)

Answer (score 2):

You could reach the function `move`by calling `globals()['move']` from within `undomove` (or any other function). Not very elegant...

Comment: I didn't even think about `globals` here.  I like that better than my `__import__` solution which is also not very elegant.